# Wix React Native Navigation change root singleScreenApp

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, velo

For Wix's React Native Navigation. If I am to create a hamburger side menu based app using  singleScreenApp, how am I suppose to change screens? Do I use the resetTo screen API? It seems that that API works like a push so I'm not sure if that's correct.

TLDR: How do you change the root screen of a singleScreenApp using Wix React Native Navigation.

Comment: Yeah `resetTo` is correct if you want to change the root.

Comment: Check out there documentation, they have pretty good explanation there. https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=resettoparams